# Logging for SSHD when started from Launchd with `-d` option?

Tags: macos, ssh, launchd

I'm working on OS X 10.8.5, fully patched. I have an updated OpenSSH server installed in `/usr/local/sbin` listening on port 1522. Connection attempts result in ***`ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`***. `sudo grep 'sshd' /var/log/* 2>/dev/null` at the server is returning almost nothing, so I'm trying to gather more information at the server on the cause.

According to [`man sshd(8)`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man8/sshd.8?query=sshd&sec=8), `-d` is debug mode and it sends verbose debug output to standard error. I added `-d` to `ProgramArguments` in the plist, but the plist also sets `StandardErrorPath` to `/dev/null`. So I'm guessing the debugging information is being discarded.

I checked [`launchctl(1)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/launchctl.1.html) man page, but I don't see what I should do to modify `StandardErrorPath` so that its logged somewhere. The man page does not even discussed the name/value pair.

How should I change the configuration so the debug logging is logged somewhere, and I know where that "somewhere" is?

---

```
$ cat /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh-7.1.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.openssh.sshd-v7.1</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/usr/local/sbin/sshd</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>-i -d</string>
    </array>
    <key>Sockets</key>
    <dict>
            <key>Listeners</key>
            <dict>
                    <key>SockServiceName</key>
                    <string>1522</string>
            </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>inetdCompatibility</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Wait</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/dev/null</string>
    <key>SHAuthorizationRight</key>
    <string>system.preferences</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. To add the `-d` argument to sshd, it should be added as a new element to the     array:

   ```
   <string>-d</string>
   ```

   The section should look like:

   ```
   <key>ProgramArguments</key>
       <array>
           <string>-i</string>
           <string>-d</string>
       </array>
   ```
2. Instead of editing the plist files directly, you can use `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy` (-h to show help).
3. There is a utility script `ssh-util.rb` that can turn logging on/off. It is part of the `OpenSSH-189` package found at: opensource.apple.com.

   [Link to ssh-util.rb](https://opensource.apple.com/source/OpenSSH/OpenSSH-189/ssh-util.rb)

   Here are the required commands to run (as produced from the ruby script):

   ```
   /usr/bin/ruby ./ssh-util.rb -l on -v --debug --dryrun
   ```

   or manually:

   ```
   sudo /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add :ProgramArguments:2 string '-ddd'" /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
   sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
   sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
   sudo touch /var/run/com.openssh.sshd-asl-enabled
   ```
4. When finished debugging,, you'll need to run either:

   ```
   /usr/bin/ruby ./ssh-util.rb -l off -v --debug --dryrun
   ```

   or manually:

   ```
   sudo /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Delete :ProgramArguments:2" /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
   sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
   sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
   sudo rm -f /var/run/com.openssh.sshd-asl-enabled
   ```

[Notes on OS X Logging](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/LoggingErrorsAndWarnings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW8-SW1)

Comment: I think the debugging information will still be discared because something needs to be done with `StandardErrorPath`.

Comment: The 'magic' is done in the last line (creating the file in /var/run).  I've just turned on logging (via the ```ssh-util.rb``` script) and ```/var/log/sshd.log``` was created.

Comment: In my answer,  I linked to ```"Notes on OS X Logging"```.   Look in ```/etc/asl``` and also have a look at ```/etc/asl.conf```.  (@Jakuje's comment concerning syslog is correct.)

Answer (score 0):

To proper logging events from `sshd` you should not set `-d` swiches, since this is reserved for debugging, but you should user `sshd_config` (not sure where is located in OSX).

In `sshd_config`, there is option `LogLevel`, which you can adjust to your needs, basically the most verbose level is `DEBUG3`, which gives you a lot of information helpful for debugging.

Comment: If I set `LogLevel=DEBUG3`, then won't it be discarded because `StandardErrorPath=/dev/null`? (Sorry to have to ask. I don't usually administer OpenSSH. Usually it "just works").

Comment: It is not logged on stderr (at least on other *nix), it is logged using syslog or other logger provided by system (usually using `/dev/log` socket).